# How to set different keywords to different colors in Java Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax-highlighting, keyword, text-coloring

Basically what I want is in my vim I have keywords like `public`, `class`, and `void` one color and keywords like `new`, `return` and `enum` a different color.

I've been looking through the eclipse keyword stuff and I can't figure out how to get different java keywords different colors.  I've looked at the `Keyword 'return'` and `Keywords excluding 'return'` options under editor syntax coloring but I want to be more specific with my colors then just `Keywords excluding 'return'.`

Any help would be appreciated

-Josh

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be only two answers:

1) Write a whole bunch of Eclipse code to provide the dozens of syntax categories offered by Vim. Then you can get the colouring you want. You could start here:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_provide_syntax_coloring_in_an_editor%3F

2) Use vim. You can set Vim as the default editor for Java files. It will open in a new window. To get Eclipse to automatically update when you save in Vim, you need to activate the "refresh automatically" setting in Window->Preference->General->Workspace. Then you can happily Vim away. This also gives you all the useful commands you get in Vim which Eclipse is lacking.

Comment: Oh I should have said that default editors are set in Window->Preferences->General->Editors->File associations. Find .java in the list, add Vim as an editor and set it as the default.